# Does epic like Mahabharata mention about Lord Shiva's personal life events?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, ganesha, parvati, kartikeya

Does it mention about - 
     1. Marriage of Shiva & Parvati
     2. Birth of Kartikeya & Ganesha 
     3. Consuming poison during churning of ocean
     4. Birth of Andhaka 
  Or some other events? 
I know Mahabharata mentions about the destruction of daksha sacrifice by veerbhadra, but it doesn't mention sati & all that (just like other puranic stories). 
Bhagwat gita 10th chapter mentions about kartikeya & gives a hint of samudra manthan while describing about Ucchaishrava horse. 
Please give reference from accurate versions of  Mahabharata.

Comment: All puranic stories of Lord Shiva l/Vishnu/Shakti  were  inspired from the Veda/Brahmanas/ epics .@aniket kumar singh

Comment: Stories of Kartikeya and others are mentioned in detail in MBH..u can find few of them in Anushasan parva..bdw Puranas other than Bhagavatam are supposed to be compiled before MBH...

Comment: I will take Critical Edition of Mahabharata as the basis here. 1. No mention of story of Shiva-Parvati marriage as far as I remember 2. Birth of Kartikeya, yes (Vana parva, I think). Ganesha not mentioned anywhere 3. Samudra manthan mentioned in Adi parva **but no mention of Shiva drinking poison** 4. Dont know about birth of Andhaka

Comment: @LazyLubber I wouldn't go by critical version, they remove whatever looks nonsense to them.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It is not so simple. Read Vishnu Sukthankar's prolegomena outling the method used for arriving at the critical edition. You can search on google. Also, for each parva, BORI has an introduction which gives a lot of information on the parva manuscripts and critical edition.

Comment: Does Mahabharata mentions only parvati, but not sati? Is it true? @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @LazyLubber If no mention of Ganesha in your critical edition then, it means that was not written by Ganesha and is not authentic... :)

Comment: @YDS It is not "my" critical edition. The critical edition was prepared long before I was even born. Also, I dont remember any AchArya arguing that Mbh is authentic because Ganesha wrote it.

Comment: but u r forcing it to be authentic over other versions..tomorrow some other group would compile versions and release new critical version..then what? whatever they hv included in their version is their opinion, others opinion might be diff..

Comment: @YDS No, I did not force anyone to accept the critical edition. If you disagree, please show me where I did that. And you are free to accept whatever you want, as authentic. Hinduism is very diverse. Who can make it homogenous?

Comment: in comments on my Q today..:)

Comment: @YDS Quote my exact statement. Else it is just mud-slinging. (I only said I could not find the verse that you quoted in the BORI edition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Chapter 62](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01063.htm) mentions:

> This work [Mahabharata] presents an account of the gods and royal sages and sacred regenerate Rishis, the sinless Kesava; **the god of gods, Mahadeva and the goddess Parvati; the birth of Kartikeya who sprang from union of Parvati with Mahadeva and was reared by many mothers**; the greatness of Brahmanas and of kine.

The story related to the birth of Kartikeya can be found in [Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b051.htm).

Consuming poison during churning of ocean can be found in [Mahabharata: Adi Parva: Chapter 18](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01019.htm):

> But with the churning still going on, the poison Kalakuta appeared at last. Engulfing the Earth it suddenly blazed up like a fire attended with fumes. And by the scent of the fearful Kalakuta, the three worlds were stupefied. And then Siva, being solicited by Brahman, swallowed that poison for the safety of the creation. The divine Maheswara held it in his throat, and it is said that from that time he is called Nilakantha (blue-throated).

Similarly, there are many stories related to Lord Shiva and Parvati in Mahaaharata.

Comment: Does it mentions about the birth of ganesha, marriage of shiva parvati, does it mentions about lord Shiva destroying demons? What are some other stories of them are described? Does lord Shiva looks exactly like puranas? @YDS

Comment: Shiva is mentioned as "slayer of Andhaka", "destroyer of the sacrifice of Daksha" at many places in MBH..also Harivamsha Purana is actually part of MBH..most of the stories can be found in MBH (including Harivamsha)..However the detailed stories of Shiva can be found in Shiva Purana same as how detailed stories related to Krishna can be found in Bhagavata Purana..